# What should be used here? Me too or me either?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference, grammaticality-in-context, negation

Seems like people have previously asked somehow a question like this, but the answers to me don't seem convincing because the source of the answer is not mentioned that's why I've decided to ask it one more time.

We all know that we use 《Me too》 when we want to respond to a positive sentence like:

> I like pizza.
> Me too

We use me neither( me either) when we want to respond to a negative sentence like:

> I don't like pizza.
> Me either

Now my question is: What is the right thing to use when the structure of your sentence is not negative or in other words it doesn't include (not) but its meaning is negative like:

> I never have breakfast at 8 o'clock.

> I hardly ever go to school.

What should we use when we want to agree with these two sentences?!

Comment: Nobody should ever say 'me either'. You can say 'me **neither**' to agree with a negative statement. You can use this with sentences with a negative meaning like the ones you showed.

Comment: Why can't we say me either?!!?!?!It is used in practical english usage and longman dictionary, but it is mentioned that it is informal. @Michael Harvey

Comment: Longman says: "This is considered to be incorrect by speakers of British English who would say me neither". I am British.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Many thanks for your answer I didn't know this.

Comment: I should be clear. It is a matter of fact that "me either" is an error in British English. It is a matter of opinion (my opinion) that it is an error in any form of English.

Answer (score 2):

If the meaning of the original sentence is negative, you agree with it using the same pattern as though it had contained the word "not":

> I never have breakfast at 8 o'clock.

You can respond:

- Neither do I.
- Nor do I.
- Nor I. (*Very formal*)
- I don't, either. (*Slightly informal*)
- Me neither. (*Informal*)
- Me either. (*Informal, considered incorrect in BrE* [1])

> I hardly ever go to school.

As above.

You wanted sources, so:

- 'Note: The word *never* makes a sentence negative. For example, “I have never been there.” / “Me neither.” This is correct.' ( https://www.englishcurrent.com/grammar/grammar-either-neither-too/ )
- '*hardly* has a negative meaning. It means *almost not at all*. So if you wish to agree with what is being said, you will also need a negative adverb and use *neither* or *nor* in response' (BBC Learning English: https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv166.shtml )

[1] https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/me-either

Answer (score 1):

Both "never" and "hardly ever" have negative force, just like "not", so "Me neither." works fine as an answer.

So, "I never eat breakfast." means the same as "I don't eat breakfast."

"Hardly ever" is equivalent to "rarely", and could also be answered by "Me neither."

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, words such as "hardly" and "never" basically imply a negation, which is why "me neither" would be an appropriate phrase choice.